# Wordpress send notification email upon new post

Tags: php, wordpress, post

So I've created a plugin that creates a new post from the front-end every time a user submits a form, now I'm trying to send an email to the admin when the post has been created. I'm doing this inside of a Class, so I'm sure thats where I'm having the problems. For some reason it isn't doing anything. I'm trying to make it create a file just for testing purposes and I'm not having any luck. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
    public function new_lead_email( $post_id ) {
    // Check to see if it is an autosave.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;

    // Check permissions
    if ( $_POST['post_type'] == 'leads'){
        // Verify that post is not a revision.
        if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

            //this is just for testing.
            file_put_contents( NHM_PLUGIN_DIR . '/assets/templates/email.html' , '<h1>Success!</h1>');

        }
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it by using this in the construct of the Class.

add_action( 'publish_post', array($this, 'new_lead_email') );

Comment: having what problems? are we supposed to guess?

Comment: @chiliNUT Good point. I just updated the post. I'm trying to make it create a file for testing, and I'm not having any luck.

Comment: do the standard stuff: echo the return value of file_put_contents, make sure you have persmissions to be writing to that file/directory, if you have terminal access `tail` the php error log.

Comment: `$_POST['post_type'] ` should be `$post = get_post($post_id); if($post->post_type == 'leads')`